# Youtube on Raspbian OS

Tags: pi-3b+, youtube

I am trying to install Youtube on a Rpi 3b+ but I get the fake apps (like Youtubuddy).Can I install Youtube on a Raspberry pi without running youtube in a browser ?

Comment: Android emulation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason why you want an app, but I will assume that you want to separate YouTube from your main web browser. In that case I think a **site specific browser** is a good solution. It will work (almost) like a dedicated app.

Below I have listed a few options that are available on Linux. I have not tried them on Linux myself, but I have tried them all on macOS. Most of them exist for Windows also.

WebCatalog
https://webcatalog.io/webcatalog/

Chromeless
https://webcatalog.io/chromeless/

Ferdi (FOSS)
https://getferdi.com

Epichrome (End of support)
https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome